# Are two teams that attempt a planet mission present with each other

Tags: star-trek-ccg

I have two teams that attempt a planet mission one after the other.
The first team has a [Emergency Transport Unit](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=923). Now the second team encounters a dilemma that would kill one of the personnel.

Emergency Transport Unit says that:

> When your personnel present is about to be killed, you may return this equipment to its owner's hand to place that personnel on your ship at this mission instead. He or she is stopped.

There is extra ruling specifying what "at this mission" means, but not what "present" means (or at least I couldn't find it)

Can I use the Emergency Transport Unit to safe that personnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually in the [core rules](https://www.trekcc.org/op/rulebook.pdf) (p 13). Section "Present"

> If a  card is  on   a  planet, it  is  present with any    other personnel and equipment on the same planet